# How to Import NOAA-CRN Data Files?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, noaa

I downloaded `.txt` files of NOAA-CRN data, which after removing data that I am not interested in and saved as `.csv` look like:

```
4           5           10
LST_DATE    LST_TIME    T_HR_AVG
YYYYMMDD    HHmm         Celsius
20150101    0           20.9
20150101    100         20.9
20150101    200         21
20150101    300         20.7
20150101    400         20.6
20150101    500         20.8
```

I want to read the files with Pandas and convert date and time in the format (because this is the format used by data from other agencies):

`2015-01-01 00:00:00`.

But I'm stuck, nothing seems to work. I am using this code to read the file:

```
parse = (lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m'))
#Import for Everglades City (CRN Station)
Y= pd.read_csv('/file.csv',
              delimiter=',', header = None, engine = 'python',
              skiprows= 3,
              usecols = [0,1,2], 
              parse_dates = [[0,1]], date_parser = parse,
                index_col=0,
               )`
```

Which gives:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Does it happen because Python cannot handle the datetime format `YYYYMMDD   HHmm`? Help will be appreciated.

Comment: No, it happens because you didn't store the data in that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with time format, possible solution is:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""4;5;10
LST_DATE,LST_TIME,T_HR_AVG
YYYYMMDD,HHmm,Celsius
20150101,0,20.9
20150101,100,20.9
20150101,200,21
20150101,300,20.7
20150101,400,20.6
20150101,500,20.8"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
#parse = (lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d %H'))

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), 
                 skiprows= 2,
                 usecols = [0,1,2],
                 )

print (df)
   YYYYMMDD  HHmm  Celsius
0  20150101     0     20.9
1  20150101   100     20.9
2  20150101   200     21.0
3  20150101   300     20.7
4  20150101   400     20.6
5  20150101   500     20.8
```

---

```
dates = df.pop('YYYYMMDD').astype(str) + df.pop('HHmm').astype(str).str.zfill(4)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(dates)
```

---

```
print (df)
                     Celsius
2015-01-01 00:00:00     20.9
2015-01-01 01:00:00     20.9
2015-01-01 02:00:00     21.0
2015-01-01 03:00:00     20.7
2015-01-01 04:00:00     20.6
2015-01-01 05:00:00     20.8
```